# Is there a way to "un-raise" exception in python?

Tags: python

I don't have control over a python library that needlessly raises a certain exception.

Is there a way to handle it with a "placebo" Exception subclass? i.e.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        # literally do nothing. return to program flow
        pass
```

Comment: Do you just want to catch the exception? You can't prevent an exception from being thrown by modifying the initializer (that only affects the exception as a value, rather than undoing the `raise`).

Comment: Since you have a certain exception, you can handle the exception by specifying the exception class in the except clause of a `try-except` block.

Comment: I could. I was hoping not to wrap all the calls and redefine the exception class or something. i want to "undo the raise"

Comment: If I understand it, you want to continue the original erring statement at the point where it failed in this other library. Correct? It seems like you want to define a different exception that this other library would raise instead of the exception it thought it was raising and the exception object's `__init__` would hack the system to ignore the error. Is that the goal? Maybe it would be easier to monkey-patch the failing function by making your own copy that handles the error differently.

Comment: It's unlikely that the function is *unconditionally* raising the exception, which means there is some avoidable condition that triggers it. It would be better to identify this condition and avoid it rather than trying to modify the exception itself (which, by the way, wouldn't prevent it from being raised).

Answer (score 5):

> raises a **certain** exception

You have a *certain* exception, you should handle the exception by specifying the exception class in the except clause of a `try-except` block.

The *placebo* approach (i.e. `except Exception...`) is only going to silence other exceptions since exceptions typically derive from `Exception` or isn't going to work at all (with your new exception class) since the raised exception is apparently not derived from the new exception class.

---

Bear in mind:

> Errors should never pass silently unless explicitly silenced

So I don't see why you would want to *undo* a raised exception without a `try-except`. The exception was not raised for nothing.

---

If you're hoping to avoid the use of `try-except` every time the function from this library is called, then you could write a wrapper function that wraps the call with a `try-except`, and then use the new function henceforth.

```
from somelib import func
from somelib import SomeException


def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
         func(*args, **kwargs)
    except SomeException:
         pass
```

Comment: Except this has different behavior from "undoing" the exception. Using the above, very line after the raise exception is *not* executed.

Comment: @Jared You seem to undermine the reason why the exception existed in the first place. How would you *undo* say a `ZeroDivisionError`?

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer is correct, if you're dealing with some strange/buggy module you can give `fuckitpy` a try!

Note that it is generally a very bad idea to let the exceptions silently pass through.

Anyhow, the basic way to use `fuckitpy` is (quoting from the docs):

```
import fuckit
#import some_shitty_module
fuckit('some_shitty_module')
some_shitty_module.some_function()
```

Also from the docs:

> Still getting errors? Chain fuckit calls. This module is like violence: if it doesn't work, you just need more of it.
>
> ```
> import fuckit
> fuckit(fuckit('some_shitty_module'))
> # This is definitely going to run now.
> some_shitty_module.some_function()
> ```

---

`fuckitpy (GitHub)`: https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy